# Whitespace appearing at bottom of page when border set to 0

Tags: html, css, firefox, whitespace

I have the following HTML sample (below), it should just cover the whole page in a big yellow div filling the available area.   It works fine when there is not much content in the div and the page is covered yellow from top to bottom, but when you make the vertical scrollbar appear by filling the div with a load of text or other content a white gap appears at the bottom. Does any know why this whitespace is appearing and how I can get rid of it either using CSS or Javascript?

I should add I have tried adding negative margins and bottom values but they just push the whitespace down they don't remove it.

I am using Firefox 32 which may help.

Thanks for your help.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#f {
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: yellow;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id='f'>
... lots of text here from ipsum ...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS it works

```
body{
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }
    #f {

        height:auto;
        right: 0px;
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
        background: yellow;
    }
```

Remove bottom top left and right in #f
and add margin 0 0 0 0 in body

Answer (score 0):

Remove "position: absolute;". It solves your problem.